# directory method of Filament doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, cloudinary, laravel-filament

I'm using Laravel and for admin panel [Filament](https://filamentphp.com/) on my website.

I also used `Spatie media library` to upload files on `Cloudinary` , as I set Laravel disk to Cloudinary.

Here is the code that is making a file input on the admin panel for **Articles** part.

```
Section::make('imsge')->schema([
   Forms\Components\SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('image')
   ->disk('cloudinary')
   ->required()
   ->image()
   ->directory('Elite Shop/blog')
   ->maxFiles(1)
   ->label('')
])->collapsible(),
```

Here I used `directory` method to specify the directory that files have to be uploaded there. As Filament documentation says:

> To change the disk and directory that files are saved in, and their visibility, use the disk(), directory() and visibility methods

But it doesn't work! Spatie is still uploading files in the root folder of Cloudinary like this:

```
1/filename.jpg
```

Although I want the path to be like this:

```
Elite Shop/blog/1/filename.jpg
```

Comment: If Spatie is using Flysystem under the hood, this [might not be an option](https://github.com/enl/flysystem-cloudinary) currently. However, in the [new](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dynamic_folders#new_upload_api_parameters) section of Cloudinary it does sound like it should at least be possible.

Comment: I'd recommend contacting Cloudinary Support and sharing with them your cloud name. They'll be able to check the upload logs for your cloud and confirm which parameters are being sent and if the `folder` field is one of them. Based on the answer to this you will know if perhaps the library that makes the call to Cloudinary is sending the parameter or not and go from there.